# Add an element at the end of a linked list

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

I wanted to make a queue using a linked list, but I couldn't make it!
can I know where's the problem? because it gives me to insert only two values!

```
typedef struct list
{
    int data;
    struct list* next;
}list;
void move_forward(list* head,list* node)
{
    if(head==NULL)  exit(1);
    while(head->next!=NULL)
       head=head->next;
    head->next=node;
}
list* insert(list* head,int value)
{
    list* node=(list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    node->data=value;
    node->next=NULL ;
    if(head==NULL)
        head=node;
    move_forward(head,node);
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Include your test code and also provide the exact expected result and actual result. For starters, in `insert` you probably need to `return` in the `head==NULL` case and not continue to call `move_forward`.

Comment: YES!! it worked!! can I know why my code didn't work ??

Comment: Well, what is `move_forward` supposed to do? It adds `node` to the end of the `head` list. But in the `head==NULL` case `head` and `node` are the same. So calling `move_forward` in that case is adding a node to the end of itself. Makes no sense in that case.

Comment: OOH! i got it know !! you are a lifesaver ,thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head 
   of a list and an int, insert a new node at the end

```
void insertAtEnd(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data) 
{ 
    /* 1. allocate node */
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 

    /* 2. put in the data  */
    new_node->data  = new_data; 

    /* 3. This new node is going to be the last node, so make next  
          of it as NULL*/
    new_node->next = NULL; 

    /* 4. If the Linked List is empty, then make the new node as head */
    if (*head_ref == NULL) 
    { 
       *head_ref = new_node; 
       return; 
    }   

    /* 5. Else traverse till the last node */
    struct Node *last = *head_ref;
    while (last->next != NULL) 
        last = last->next; 

    /* 6. Change the next of last node */
    last->next = new_node; 
    return;     
}
```